# FLAnimatedImage_AFNetworking error File not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm trying to use this https://github.com/jagbolanos/FLAnimatedImage_AFNetworking and I'm getting the following error:

> AFHTTPRequestOperation.h **file not found**.

I have tried using `AFNetworking` and `FLAnimatedImage` by just dragging the files in and by Cocoapods.

Any solutions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> AFHTTPRequestOperation.h file not found.

The error occurs because of the path problem. The Xcode is not getting the path of this file.

I was able to solve the same problem with the following code.

Add this to the Library Search Paths in Build Settings and make sure you select recursive, delete other library paths which might be absolute paths.

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)
```

May be it will help you.

Comment: When you solved the problem, was it with the current version of AFNetworking and FLAnimatedImage? I downloaded an older version that does contain AFHTTPRequestOperation.h and the error went away. However, now I have another error when I try to call animatedImage.setAnimatedImageWithURL - value of type FLAnimatedImage has no member (name of the method)